# observe changes in a different viewmodel

Tags: observable, reactiveui, raise

I'm using reactiveui with dynamic data.  It's working fine if all the changes are handle in the same viewmodel.

The problem I have is one of the field in a class is actually coming from a database, this field is shared between two viewmodel, if I update it in one viewmodel, I want it notify the changes to the other viewmodel.  How do I do that.

Previously, in the typical event driven model, I just subscribe to the event.

```
private string _Name;
    [CategoryAttribute("NotUsed "),
    DescriptionAttribute("DisplayName"),
    DisplayName("Name"), Browsable(true) ]
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _Name, value);
            this.RaiseValidation(nameof(_Name));

        }
    }
```

that is, when I update the Name in the dialog box and close it, I want this to update the field in the main module.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Rx or ReactiveUI expert, but the way I would do it is to create a service that retrieves your data from the database.  Then each ViewModel would retrieve this class from the service as an `Observable`.  When one ViewModel alters the class, you need to notify the service that changes have been made.  Then the service will send out notifications to all subscribed ViewModels that this class has changed.

```
public class DataService
{
   private BehaviorSubject<MyClass> subject;
   public IObservable<MyClass> => subject.AsObservable();

   public DataService()
   {
      // code to get the data from database and initialize the BehaviorSubject 
      // with the starting data.

       subject = new BehaviorSubject<MyClass>(...instance of class...);
   }

   public void MyClassHasChanged(MyClass class)
   {
      //update database then...
      subject.OnNext(class);
   }
}
```

And if this data is in a list... then `DynamicData` would seriously shine here.